# Why does terminal switches to nano console on merge in ubuntu?

Tags: git, ubuntu, merge, nano, terminator

Only in the time of Merge, the **Terminal** || **Terminator** both switches to nano console in ubuntu 14.01 and i get struck here. Not able to move out of it and it takes too much time to get updated, but windows not causing any such kind of issues.

Anybody has faced it. How to overcome from this? I don't want to get switched to **`GNU nano 2.2.6`** console.

> Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
>   especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch. Lines
>   starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the
>   commit.

Please assist with this.

Comment: It sounds like this is simply Git prompting you for a commit message. Do you want to use some other editor for commit messages?

Comment: @chris, for other commit messsages like push and in the time of pull without merge doesn't cause this problem. Why the editor is switching is wat my quesiton?

Comment: Because you are doing an operation that creates a new commit, and that requires a commit message. `push` doesn't create new commits (it simply copies existing commits to the name remote), nor does a pull without merge (which I'm interpreting as a pull resulting in a fast-forward merge).

Answer (score 3):

Check your `$EDITOR` environment variable as well as the setting of `git config core.editor`. One of those is probably set to `nano`.